# python datefinder's find_dates method is not returning the expected result

Tags: python, pandas, datefinder

I have a column in Pandas dataframe 'Comment Text' which contains the dates in this format(showing here, only first observation):

```
7/09/2018 11:59:37 AM;12:01:33 PM;00:01:56
```

Adding Dataframe sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Common Text':['7/09/2018 11:59:37 AM;12:01:33 PM;00:01:56', 'Adams Gill Christ  4 Oct 2017    02:52 PM', '4/08/2017 4:30:49 PM ;4:37:23 PM;00:06:34', '5/07/2018 10:14:03 AM ;10:21:35 AM;00:07:31', 'the call was made on 20 Jun 2017\nbut call not found on system', 'Call made on 7/03/2018 8:22:25 AM', 'Review is during 30 May to 1 March 2018']})
```

But when I did something like this:

```
import datefinder
FD = datefinder.find_dates(df['Comment Text'][0])

for dates in FD:
    print(dates)
```

I got the following result:

```
2018-07-09 11:59:37
2019-06-20 12:01:33
2019-06-20 00:01:56
```

Which is not correct as I was expecting only `2018-07-09` to return as result.

Comment: The example data you gave is the data from 1 row, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly and your data always has the two date structures you've shown as example. You can use regex.

```
# Make example data
df = pd.DataFrame({'Common Text':['7/09/2018 11:59:37 AM;12:01:33 PM;00:01:56', 
                                  'Adams Gill Christ  4 Oct 2017    02:52 PM', 
                                  '4/08/2017 4:30:49 PM ;4:37:23 PM;00:06:34', 
                                  '5/07/2018 10:14:03 AM ;10:21:35 AM;00:07:31', 
                                  'the call was made on 20 Jun 2017\nbut call not found on system']})

                                         Common Text
0         7/09/2018 11:59:37 AM;12:01:33 PM;00:01:56
1          Adams Gill Christ  4 Oct 2017    02:52 PM
2          4/08/2017 4:30:49 PM ;4:37:23 PM;00:06:34
3        5/07/2018 10:14:03 AM ;10:21:35 AM;00:07:31
4  the call was made on 20 Jun 2017\nbut call not...
```

Use [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html).

```
s = df['Common Text'].str.extract('(.+?(?=\s\d{1,2}:\d{2}:\d{2}))|(\d{1,2}\s[A-Za-z]{3}\s\d{4})')
df['Date'] = s[0].fillna(s[1])



                                         Common Text         Date
0         7/09/2018 11:59:37 AM;12:01:33 PM;00:01:56    7/09/2018
1          Adams Gill Christ  4 Oct 2017    02:52 PM   4 Oct 2017
2          4/08/2017 4:30:49 PM ;4:37:23 PM;00:06:34    4/08/2017
3        5/07/2018 10:14:03 AM ;10:21:35 AM;00:07:31    5/07/2018
4  the call was made on 20 Jun 2017\nbut call not...  20 Jun 2017
```

**Explanation:**

- `(.+?(?=\s\d{1,2}:\d{2}:\d{2}))`: Extract everything before the pattern of time, which is `99:99:99`
- `(\d{1,2}\s[A-Za-z]{3}\s\d{4})`: Extract the pattern: one or two numbers, space,  3 letters, space, 4 numbers

Comment: Then please extend your example data more with other examples.

Comment: See edit, it captures the two patterns of your date. @loveR

Comment: thanks. nice work. but I was wondering why it returned `NaN` for `Review Period from 29/10/2019`

Comment: I dont see `29/10/2019` in your example data? @loveR

Comment: I tried this... `str.extract('((?:(?:[0-2]?\\d{1})|(?:[3][01]{1}))[-:\\/.](?:[0]?[1-9]|[1][012])[-:\\/.](?:(?:[1]{1}\\d{1}\\d{1}\\d{1})|(?:[2]{1}\\d{3})))(?![\\d])|(.+?(?=\s\d{1,2}:\d{2}:\d{2}))|(\d{1,2}\s[A-Za-z]{3}\s\d{4})')`

Comment: Please edit your example data so it includes the problem which my regular expression doesnt capture @loveR

Comment: In the last line, what do you expect to extract here, `1 march 2018`?